# Multiply and Roundup to the Nearest 500

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Al has a value of 270,000.  I need a formula that will multiply A1 by 2, and then roundup to the nearest 500, without exceeding 500,000.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use MIN to return 500,000 if over and MROUND to round to neared 500:

```
=MIN(MROUND(A1*2,500),500000)
```

---

To round up:

```
=MIN(MROUND(A1*2+249,500),500000)
```

Comment: I don't know how to that. :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
=MIN(ROUNDUP(A1*2/500,0)*500,500000)
```

Just another option